# How to change the URL in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created all the file in my folder

[image]

Now when I am accessing the product_2.php I am getting the URL

```
http://localhost/Test/product_2
```

Now I have to display the URL like

```
http://localhost/Test/product/product_2
```

I added `RewriteRule ^product/product_2  product_2.php` in the `.htaccess` but it's not working.

**.htaccess file**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^product/product_2  product_2.php
```

Would you help me out in this issue?

Comment: I feel like it would be easier to throw product_2 in a new folder called product

Comment: Add `RewriteBase /Test/` after `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: @Derek, I have more than 4 files and I have to update link and script in each file if I created the product folder

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to your .htaccess file.

```
Redirect /Test/product/product_2 http://localhost/Test/product_2
```

Comment: what should I add in the html anchor tag <a href="product_2" class="link">product_2</a>. Is it right?

Comment: As per the description, if I have understood correctly, you want to display the URL http://localhost/Test/product/product_2 instead of http://localhost/Test/product_2. So basically you need to add the new URL i.e., http://localhost/Test/product/product_2 in the href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it before and with a little change

```
RewriteRule ^product/product_2 product_2 [QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Anyway, this is not the best practice I would recommend.. you should redirect all of your calls to index.php and handle them there, something like that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

then in index.php

```
$requested_url = $_GET['url'];
```

and from here you can decide what to do, you can include the wanted file or even do something more clever.

Comment: for the Second htaccess code can you share some example?

Comment: And what should I add in the html anchor tag <a href="product_2" class="link">product_2</a>. Is it right?

Comment: the simple thing would be to include the file you want base on the requested url.. the advanced way would be to use an mvc structure to handle those calls.
you can take a look here: https://github.com/shahafan/SAmvc-App although you'll need composer for it

Comment: about the href.. you can do whatever you decide to do.. just handle it right :)

Comment: I added your first paragraph htaccess code and the link is <a href="product_2" class="link">product_2</a> but it's not working. It's showing http://localhost/Test/product_2

Comment: Sorry, which one are you talking about?

Comment: this line RewriteRule ^product/product_2 product_2 [QSA,NC]
is just telling the server that if someone tries to reach product/product_2 you should actually call product_2, i've just added it before your code that you've said is working

Comment: Sir, I haven't said. It's working. I tried but it's not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170783/discussion-between-shahaf-antwarg-and-user9437856).